# Is there a way to configure the menu items that will be displayed on right click on a secondary tile of an UWP app?

Tags: uwp

I would like to know if there is a way to configure a secondary tile so that the context menu, displayed on the right click, will include "App settings" in the "More" item group(just like it does with primary tiles). I couldn't find anything on this issue in both uwp samples app and documentation, so I thought someone here might be aware of how to solve my problem.

This the context menu of a primary tile

[image]
and

this is the one of a secondary tile

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure the menu items that will be displayed on right click on a secondary tile of an UWP app?

I have to say, there is no way to make secondary tile right click include "App settings" in the "More" item group. and the functions where in the more group is managed by system. if you have resisted tile notification. it will show  turn live tile off automatically.

And if you want to custom live tile switch, you could refer to [JumpList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.startscreen.jumplist?view=winrt-22000) document and place this function in jump-list task.